# PHP SVG Function Code128 unreadable with laser scanner

Tags: php, svg, barcode

Ok so I've found this [PHP application](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsvgbarcode/) on the Internet and intended to use it on a HTML page without CSS (as I will be using google cloud print and it cant read local css and is not possible to send the css too) and the SVG output was my solution. As i was testing away those functions (Code128, Code39, EAN13, EAN8 and UPCA) I've noticed the only ones that my laser scanner wasnt been able to read were Code128 and EAN8 but Code128 is the most important one for my situation.

Checking the code I was able to noticed that the last item on the Array in Code128.php had an extra number (7 digits) and by doing some research this [link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script88.php) proves im right (both in same order just check the last item), but fixing it wasnt enough.

How can I make this work?

Code128.php (Function)

```
<?php
//+32=ASCII Total: 106.                   
$code128=array('212222', '222122', '222221', '121223', '121322', '131222', '122213', '122312', '132212', '221213', '221312', '231212', '112232', '122132', '122231', '113222', '123122', '123221', '223211', '221132', '221231', '213212', '223112',
    '312131', '311222', '321122', '321221', '312212', '322112', '322211', '212123', '212321', '232121', '111323', '131123', '131321', '112313', '132113', '132311', '211313', '231113', '231311', 
    '112133', '112331', '132131', '113123', '113321', '133121', '313121', '211331', '231131', '213113', '213311', '213131', '311123', '311321', '331121', '312113', '312311', '332111', '314111', '221411', '431111', '111224', '111422', '121124', 
    '121421', '141122', '141221', '112214', '112412', '122114', '122411', '142112', '142211', '241211', '221114', '413111', '241112', '134111', '111242', '121142', '121241', '114212', '124112', 
    '124211', '411212', '421112', '421211', '212141', '214121', '412121', '111143', '111341', '131141', '114113', '114311', '411113', '411311', '113141', '114131', '311141', '411131', '211412', '211214', '211232', '233111', '21');

//Congugure
$unit='px';//Unit
$bw=1.5;//bar width
$height=50*$bw;
$fs=8*$bw;//Font size
$yt=45*$bw;
$dx=2*$bw;
$x=5*$bw;
$y=2.5*$bw;
$bl=35*$bw;

function checksum($str){
    $cstr=str_split($str);
    $count=count($cstr);
    $sum=ord($cstr[0])-32;
    for ($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){
        $sum+=(ord($cstr[$i])-32)*$i;
    }
    $sum=$sum % 103;
    $sum+=32;
    return chr($sum);
}

function draw($text,$type='B',$check=false){
    global $unit,$x,$code128,$height,$bw,$fs,$dx,$yt;
    $type=preg_replace('/\W/','',$type);
    $type=substr($type,0,1);
    $type=strtoupper($type);
    $clong=(strlen($text)+4)*11;
    $width=$bw*$clong;
    switch($type){
        case'A':
        $start=$code128[103];
        break;
        case'B':
        $start=$code128[104];
        break;
        case'C':
        $start=$code128[105];
        break;
        default:
        $start=$code128[104];
        break;

    }
    $ctext=$start.$text;
    if ($check) {
    $text.=checksum($ctext);
    }
    $text=str_split($text);
    $img='';
    $img.= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n";
    $img.= "<svg width='$width$unit' height='$height$unit' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>\n";
    //Draw Guard bar.
    $img.= "<desc>First Guard</desc>\n";
    //StartCode
    $img.=drawchar($start);

    //Begin Content
    foreach($text as $char){
        $index=ord($char)-32;
        $xt=$x+$dx;
        $img.= "<desc>$char</desc>\n";
        $img.=drawchar($code128[$index]);
        $img.= "<text x='$xt$unit' y='$yt$unit' font-family='Arial' font-size='$fs'>$char</text>\n";
    }
    //End guard bar.
    $img.=drawchar($code128[106]);
    $img.='</svg>';
    return $img;
}
function drawchar($char){
    global $unit,$x,$y,$bl,$height,$bw,$fs,$bw;
    $val=str_split($char);
    $img='';
    $j=0;
    foreach($val as $bar){
        $num=(int)$bar;
        $w=$bw*$num;
        if(!($j % 2)){
            $img.= "<rect x='$x$unit' y='$y$unit' width='$w$unit' height='$bl$unit' fill='black' stroke-width='0' />\n";
        }
        $x += $w;
        $j++;
    }
    return $img;
}
?>
```

And the request (code128example.php)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
include 'Code128.php';
$code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] :'CODE128'; 
header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
echo draw($code);
?>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the `draw(var)` function is imported correctly and functioning as expected? Also, are there any errors logged in the server (I suspect Apache), in the processor (PHP [your_version]) or even in the Client that is making that request (I myself test my applications with Apache Firefox and Google Chrome, as both have great debugger toos such as Firebug).... and a minor detail, you have `\n` as linebreaks, instead of the expected `</br>` ones

Comment: @Bonatti I checked and switched those {\n} to {<br>} but nothing chanced, I can confirm the {draw(var)} is imported correctly as i get a return with the codebar but when I print it my laser scanner it does not recognize it, Code128 and EAN8 are the only ones my scanner won't read properly after printed.

Comment: I will be honest.... I tried to check source for a way to help, but that is a "product" that was abandonned for at least 6 years, with less than a hundred uses, and no documentation.... Then I gave up on reading that tool. Try to get something newer, or that at least on that has some users. Finally, if this is  aproduct/task you must do, read related documentation regarding Barcodes, then try to salvage the source code, and implement yourself whats missing.

Comment: @Bonatti Yeah I'vve noticed that too but as I said of the 5 functions (Code128, Code39, ENA8, ENA13 UPCA), 3 worked just fine with my laser scanner, so I thought that with a little effort I could manage to make it work too. But thanks for your help anyway.